# Adding a line break every x characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, rstudio

**What I want to do**:

Add line breaks approximately every x characters to a written text, without breaking words. It would also be great if I could add "# " after each line break. I usually use Notepad++ to manipulate such texts.

*Example:*

```
set the random seed to 144 and use sample.split function to select the 70% of observations for the training set
```

Becomes

```
# set the random seed to 144 and use sample.split function 
# to select the 70% of observations for the training set
```

**Why I want to do it**

I'm working in Rstudio and somtimes paste in comments from already written text into my code.

**What I've tried**

I'm blank. I'm just doing it manually, but I realized I could save a lot of time by automating this process.

Comment: Rstudio now has this functionality via shortcut key `ctrl + shift + c` followed by `ctrl + shift + /`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record a macro for this on Notepad++.
I would follow these steps while recording.

1. Place the cursor at the start.
2. Move the cursor 70 times to the right (using the right arrow)
3. When you are at the 70th character press the `Control` and the `Right Arrow` keys.
4. This will make the cursor to jump to the start of the next word.
5. Press `#` and `Enter`.

Stop the macro and play back.

Or you could use something like [this](http://textmechanic.com/Add-Remove-Line-Breaks.html).  It does exactly what you ask.